# API for resizing images in laravel 5.4

Tags: laravel, image, api

i am working on a marketing website with laravel 5.4
i need to upload and load lots of images on the website, if i load the original image every time, it will going slow. so i need your suggestions
*

1. should i store the image with two quality? (original and
   resized)
2. store the original images, resize them when they loaded
   on the screen? (need an ***API***)

share some ideas and the solutions please!
if you have such an API, please share!

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Laravel does not have a default resize of image. But most laravel developers use 'Image intervention' in handling the image. (Easy to use)

To install (Image intervention):

STEP 1 Run

```
 composer require intervention/image
```

STEP 2 On your config/app.php:

In the $providers array, add the following:

```
  Intervention\Image\ImageServiceProvider::class
```

In the $aliases array,add the following:

```
 'Image' => Intervention\Image\Facades\Image::class
```

If you have problems your GD librabry is missing, intall it

```
 PHP5: sudo apt-get install php5-gd
 PHP7: sudo apt-get install php7.0-gd
```

~~ To use on your controller ~~

STEP 3 On top of your controller

```
use Intervention\Image\ImageManagerStatic as Image;
```

STEP 4 On your method (there are several ways but this will give you an idea)

```
 if($request->hasFile('image')) {

   $image       = $request->file('image');
   $filename    = $image->getClientOriginalName();

   $image_resize = Image::make($image->getRealPath());              
   $image_resize->resize(300, 300);
   $image_resize->save(public_path('images/ServiceImages/' 
  .$filename));

}
```

Comment: thank you, it worked.
but now the problem is, it is not uploading image with size more than 1MB. any sulution?

Comment: and one more, how to get the width and height of the uploaded image?, i mean, according to their width and height i want to resize. not like i do now. for example when a image is 1024x680 so if i resize it with a default value like 300x300, it not good.

Comment: You can get width and height  of image by :
         $width = Image::make('public/foo.jpg')->width();
         $height = Image::make('public/foo.jpg')->height();